# Mongoose Populate Sub Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bluebird, mongoose-populate

I've the following schemas:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    fb_id: String,
    subscriptions: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Subscription' }]
});

var SubscriptionSchema = new Schema({
    asin: String,
    price: Number,
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
}, { timestamps: true });
```

The database contains the following documents:

**user**

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a397dd97d6682fb0aeb1a01"
    },
    "fb_id": "99999999999999",
    "__v": 0
}
```

**subscription**

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a397dd94ee7e13f43fefa42"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2017-12-19T21:00:09.199Z"
    },
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2017-12-19T21:00:09.199Z"
    },
    "asin": "ABCDEFGHI001",
    "price": 0.98,
    "user": {
        "$oid": "5a397dd97d6682fb0aeb1a01"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Why this function:

```
const test = (userId) => {
    User.findOne({ fb_id: userId }).populate('subscriptions').exec()
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
};
```

Always returns a user with an empty subscriptions array? Many thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm using bluebird promise with mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

You've put the user ID in to the subscription which means if you were to fetch the subscription and populate the user you'd get that subscription with an array of subscribed users.

The User document in your example doesn't have any subscriptions associated with it so it won't populate anything.

When you create the user you'll need to add the subscription to the document. E.g.

```
let newUser = new User({
    db_id:"99999999999999",
    subscriptions:["5a397dd94ee7e13f43fefa42"]
});
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand...I want to create a user and then, after some time, "attach" a subscription to it. So basically, when I create a user, is normal that it has no subs.

Comment: Fair enough - then create the User model with an empty array and when you subscribe each user to a Subscription you'll need to push the Subscription ObjectID to the Users subscriptions.

Comment: What do you mean by "push"? Isn't it enough to use the User ObjectID inside the creation of the new sub? new Subscription({ asin: 'ABCDEFGHI001', price: 0.98, user: user._id })

Comment: No because that data isn't fetched when you fetch the user. By push I meant array.push() i.e. add an item to the end of the array.

So, in short, make the new Subscription, get its ID, get the User, add the Subscription ID to the users Subscriptions and then save the User.

Answer (score 0):

As of mongoose 4.5, you can accomplish this with virtual populate: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals.

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  fb_id: String,
});

const SubscriptionSchema = new Schema({
  asin: String,
  price: Number,
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
});

UserSchema.virtual('subscriptions', {
  ref: 'Subscription',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'user',
});
```